# Firebase Performance of Hashmap versus TreeMap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app, I am using Firebase Database to store the data. There are some values that I want to store in the Firebase Database as a `Map<String, Integer>`.

When retrieving my data for display on the Android UI, I mostly need data  "sorted by key".

My question is from a performance viewpoint whether I should declare the Map as a Hashmap or a Treemap? For e.g. like

```
Map<String, Integer> myData = new Hashmap<>();
```

or

```
Map<String, Integer> myData = new Treemap<>();
```

Of the above 2 options, which would give me a better performance for retrieval of data. Each Map size is expected to be in range of 0 to 10,000 entries. And there could be anywhere between 5-11 such Maps in my database for each user.

My question is specifically to target understanding performance of Firebase and not a general question about the difference between 2 map types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes, [Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [Treemap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) implement the `Map` interface. Both classes offer mostly the same functionality but the most important difference between this classes is the order in which iteration through the entries will happen.

- `HashMap` offers no guarantees about the iteration order and it can also change completely when new elements are added/deleted. Lookup-array structure, based on hashCode(), equals() implementations, O(1) runtime complexity for inserting and searching, unsorted.
- `TreeMap` will iterate according to the `natural ordering` of the containing keys according to their `compareTo()` method. This can also be accomplished with an external Comparator. It also implements the [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface. Tree structure, based on compareTo() implementation, O(log(N)) runtime complexity for inserting and searching, sorted.

Use a `HashMap` unless you have some need for ordering. **`HashMap is faster!`**. But as you said that you mostly need your data "sorted by key", just use the `TreeMap`.